# CakePHP - Users Plugin - Rendering different Views on different servers

Tags: cakephp, plugins, view

I have a very wired issue.
I usw CakePHP 4.x and CakeDc-Users-Plugin.

For the Login method i use a custom View in Templates/cakedc/Users/Users/login.php

It works perfectly fine locally (Win11+xampp).

But on the live Server (Ubuntu+Apache) it renders the default view from the vendors folder.

Any ideas?

Everything else works fine - i even cloned the Project new - twice...

Comment: Did a typo there: of course ist the View in Templates/Plugin/cakedc/Users/Users..

Answer (score 0):

i found the issue - just in case someone runs into the same problem.
Looks like xampp(windows) doesn't really care about letter capitalization (neither so does git) - but ubuntu does.